# how to keep the activity UI view when typing to edittext in android.

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, floating

I have one activity with a few edit text. Every time I focus on one edittext. I will continue to next, next until I finish all the edit text typing in the page. I want to have the keyboard floating so that I can choose which edittext to type. Please help. Thx.

Comment: keyboard floating you can choose any text box when keyboard is up

Answer (score 0):

use Edittext property  `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

and refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions)